# PHPMailer не прекращать выполнение скрипта из за ошибки

Tags: php, phpmailer

С помощью PHPMailer сделал рассылку оповещений. Проблема в том, что списки получателей которые загружаю иногда бывают с ошибками. Если попадается адрес с ошибкой то прерывается выполнение всего скрипта.

> Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: Invalid address:
>   (to):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 

$mail->Host = ""; 
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = ""; 
$mail->Password = ""; 

try {
   $mail->AddAddress('em,ail@gmail.com',''.$FirstName.' '.$LastName.'');
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo "Bad email";
}

$bcc_array = explode(",", $bcc_emails);

foreach($bcc_array as $bccer){
   $mail->AddBCC($bccer);
}

$mail->SetFrom($sender_email,$sender_name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;

$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->AddAttachment($file_name);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

if(!$mail->send()) {
$alert_failed_insert=false;
} else {
$alert_failed_insert=true;
}
```

Comment: может где bad email впихнуть https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: Не должно прерываться так как вы ловите исключение и обрабатываете его. Проверьте что это именно то исключение, которое кидается, и должно быть в порядке. В противном случае проверьте что вы ловите также и ошибку (Error) если она кидается, которая не наследует исключению. (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.errors.php7.php)